# Using Eslint within vite to lint all .js files within that directory and subdirectories

Tags: javascript, eslint, vite

I am trying to lint all js files in the target directory and all subdirectories, but I can't find a way to do it.
For details I use vite for vanilla javascript projects which is located higher up the hierarchy than the to build directory (therefor it is necessary that it only lint target directory and all subdirectories of that) and trying to lint all js files in there, I managed to lint only the input file (file1.js). Also I am going to zip the entire directory after soo creating a .js output for every file is not desirable. The hierarchy is as follows.

```
directory
| file1.js
_ subdir
  | file2.js
   _ subdir
    |file3.js
    |file4.js
```

How can I make sure it lints all files inside the target folder and subdirectories?

I already tried the override within the .eslintrc.cjs but it doesn't lint the others:

```
overrides: [
        {
          files: ['**/*.js'],
          extends: ['eslint:recommended'],
        },
    ],
```